# Does the Rascal unit testing framework has support for a test fixture?

Tags: rascal

In Rascal you can define test functions by specifying the `test` modifier on a boolean function. And running them by typing `:test` at the Rascal command line. See details [over here](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Rascal.html#/Rascal/Declarations/Function/Function.html).

Is it somehow possible to also specify test fixtures (for a test suite)? Like for example `setup()` and `teardown()` functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a setup function by including a global variable in the module you write the tests in:

```
bool s = setup(); // is called 

int myGlobal1 = 2;

bool setup() {
  myGlobal1 = 1;
}
```

`teardown` isn't so much necessary since we do not have that much state in Rascal other than these global variables.

Another, perhaps better, way of sharing state between tests is the use of @memo functions:

```
@memo
value getMyExampleData(int input) = ...;

test bool myTest1() {
  myData = getMyExampleData(1);

  return /shouldContainThis x := myData;
}

test bool myTest2() {
  myData = getMyExampleData(1);

  return /shouldContainThisToo y := myData;
}
```

The second call to getMyExampleData will be really fast since the result is taken from a cache. If the JVM runs out of memory, the cache is cleared automatically.

BTW, there is also some support for random testing, as in:

```
test bool myTest(int i, int j) = i + j == j + i;
```

Then the test runner will generate a lot of random input for the parameters of the test function. You can influence the input generation as well via some tags. Let us know if you are interested.

Comment: Any more (online) information about what `@memo` does exactly? Will ask Monday about random testing support tags.

Comment: I don't think we documented @memo yet. but there is not much about it to know. All it does is cache the results of a function, when given the same parameters it produces the result from the cache instead of recomputing. The cache is freed when the Java GC needs more memory (try and predict that :-)

Comment: be careful with annotations, in Rascal annotations are not considered when deciding equality. This also holds for `@memo` , so if your value only differs in the annotations, don't use `@memo` cause it is going to hurt.